# White-space generating "invalid character in identifier"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects:

```
obj_map = [ 
    {"editable": "true", "col_name": "numberEnds", "display": "true"},
    {"editable": "false", "col_name": "id", "display": "false"},
    {"editable": "true", "col_name": "store_code", "display": "true"},
    {"editable": "true", "col_name": "store_id", "display": "true"}

              ]
```

Which generates the following error:

```
{"editable": "true", "col_name": "numberEnds", "display": "true"},
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Why is whitespace being interpreted as an invalid character in this scenario?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error.. are you sure this is all of your code? Is there anything before it that may have lead to this?

Comment: Runs fine for me. AFAIK, Python doesn't have an error with: "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier".

Comment: I am not getting any error with this. using python version 3.4 in ubuntu.

Comment: Well, looks like I was wrong...

Comment: Thanks guys. Turns out the code was initially pasted from Libre Office, rather than a plain text editor, which encodes whitespace differently to Sublime.